# CoffeeScript only executing last line

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript, manually changing the value of a radio button. If one is selected, it sets the selected radio button to true, and the sibling one false.

However this code always returns both radio buttons as `false`, or both as `true` if I put the true statement first. How do I get both lines to execute, without overwriting each other?

```
$(".quote_second_mortgage").on 'change', 'input', ->
    $(this)[0].value = "true"
    $(this).parent().first().children(":first-child")[0].value = "false"
```

JS is

```
$(".quote_second_mortgage").on('change', 'input', function() {
  $(this)[0].value = "true";
  return $(this).parent().first().children(":first-child")[0].value = "false";
});
```

Edited `Coffeescript`:

```
 $(".quote_second_mortgage").on 'change', 'input', ->
    this.value = "true"
    $(this).parent().first().children(":first-child")[0].value = "false"
```

HTML, from Rails app:

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
        <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="quote_escrow_true" name="quote[escrow]" type="radio" value="false">
        <span class="radio-text">hah</span>
    </label>

    <label class="radio">
        <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="quote_escrow_true" name="quote[escrow]" type="radio" value="false">
        <span class="radio-text">hah</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You're *half* using jQuery. Use `$(this).val("true")` or `this.value = "true"`, but don't mix the two. There is no value whatsoever in wrapping `this` in `$()` only to *immediately* get the element back with `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks. I cleaned it up (see updated), but am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try like this `$(@).prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Tried, but they both get stuck as `true` or both stuck as `false`

Comment: Added. It's from a rails app using `SimpleForm`

Comment: can you change it like below:

    $(".quote_second_mortgage").on 'change', 'input', ->
        $(@).prop('checked', true)
        $(@).closest('label').siblings()
             .find('input').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Set last one to `false`